# How many NPCs can you interact with in SMO?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

There are a lot of NPCs in Super Mario Odyssey. How many are there throughout the game which you can interact with (i.e. press A to open a dialogue)?

I am counting NPCs who start minigames, who work at the Crazy Cap shop, and who you can interact with at one point in the game but can’t later.

> (Like Princess Peach.)

Does anyone have a tally of how many NPCs fit these criteria?

Comment: Have you done any counting yourself? This could be quite a task; would be helpful to know who/where you've counted already.

Comment: @Kozaky I hadn’t, yet. I just did the first few sections of the game, and posted that as a partial answer.

Comment: Why is this important? How is this useful information for other players, other than as trivia?

Comment: @MageXy I don’t see anything that says that trivia questions are off-topic. I’ve seen plenty of questions about how many NPCs are in game X on here - downvotes, perhaps, but still open.

Comment: It's not off-topic, which is why I'm not voting to close the question. I just don't think it's a good or useful question, hence the downvote.

Comment: @MageXy could help someone who's trying to 100% the game without directly looking up the locations of each moon. It all depends on how you wanna play a game.

Comment: @Atav32 Much as I appreciate the support, it’s a bit misplaced here. While there’s overlap, these are all the interactable NPCs in the game, not just ones that give you moons.

Answer (score 4):

## SPOILER ALERT

Rather than posting large portions of this answer in spoilers, I’m putting this one big spoiler alert at the top. You are hereby warned.

I have tried to put the NPCs in the same general area next to each other on the list, and in the order of the general progression of the level. In Sand Kingdom, where several areas aren’t part of the level progression, I stuck them in to continue the general clockwise patten of the level.

## This is a Work In Progress

---

## Mushroom Kingdom

1. Toad by the fountain (after meeting Peach everywhere)
2. Luigi
3. Purple Crazy Cap Toad
4. Yellow Crazy Cap Toad
5. Hint Toad
6. Uncle Amiibo
7. Talkatoo
8. Music Toad
9. Roving Racer
10. Scoreboard
11. Shepherd Toad
12. Hat and Seek Bonneter
13. Courtyard Gate Keeper Toad
14. Toad Defender
15. Paint Toad (next to rocket)
16. Paint Toad (in mini game)
17. Toad that points toward green pipe
18. Toad that comments on Yoshi
19. Bonneter looking for friend
20. Toad in front of castle
21. Peach
22. Toadette
23. Hint Art
24. Captain Toad

## Cap Kingdom

1. Hint Toad
2. Uncle Amiibo
3. Luigi
4. Talkatoo
5. Purple Crazy Cap Bonneter
6. Yellow Crazy Cap Bonneter
7. Bonneter Blockade
8. Hidden treasure Bonneter
9. Peach
10. Hint Art
11. Sign on steps to Sometimes Bridge
12. Roving Racer
13. Scoreboard
14. Captain Toad

## Cascade Kingdom

1. Hint Toad
2. Uncle Amiibo
3. Taxi Tostarenan
4. Roving Racer
5. Scoreboard
6. Spin throw sign
7. Luigi
8. Purple Crazy Cap Bonneter
9. Yellow Crazy Cap Bonneter
10. Talkatoo
11. Peach
12. Caveman Bonneter
13. Captain Toad
14. Hint Art

## Sand Kingdom

1. Hint Toad
2. Uncle Amiibo
3. Bonneter looking for friend
4. Hat and Seek Bonneter
5. Taxi Tostarenan
6. Jaxi
7. Jaxi Stand (Tostarena Town)
8. Tostarenan talking about map
9. Tostarenan talking about tourists
10. Purple Crazy Cap Tostarenan
11. Yellow Crazy Cap Tostarenan
12. Luigi
13. Slots Tostarenan
14. Tostarenan talking about amiibo
15. Tostarenan by party room
16. Hint Art
17. Music Toad
18. Tostarenan on path to ruins
19. Glydon
20. Sphinx
21. Shepherd Tostarenan
22. Jaxi Stand (NW Reaches)
23. Roving Racers
24. Scoreboard
25. Poster Cleaner Tostarenan
26. Jaxi Stand (near the Sphinx)
27. Slingshot Tostarenan
28. Action Guide Tostarenan
29. Peach
30. Jaxi Stand (inverted pyramid)
31. Tostarenan hinting to Jaxi Ruins entrance
32. Tostarenan hinting to Jaxi’s ability to run on poison
33. Jaxi Stand (Jaxi Ruins)
34. Koopa Trace Walking
35. Jaxi Stand (Oasis)

## Lake Kingdom

1. Roving Racer
2. Scoreboard
3. Hint Toad
4. Uncle Amiibo
5. Luigi
6. Talkatoo
7. Lochlady on the bottom of the Water Plaza
8. Secret Room Lochlady
9. Captain Toad
10. Lochlady by the door to the dress
11. Lochlady admiring the dress
12. Purple Crazy Cap Lochlady
13. Yellow Crazy Cap Lochlady
14. Cowboy Style Sister
15. Astronaut Style Sister
16. Pirate Style Sister
17. Peach
18. Hint Art

## Wooded Kingdom

1. Steam Gardener talking about Deep Woods
2. Hint Toad
3. Uncle Amiibo
4. Purple Crazy Cap Steam Gardener
5. Yellow Crazy Cap Steam Gardener
6. Luigi
7. Sphinx
8. Sign in the tunnel
9. Music Toad
10. Talkatoo
11. Sign in the lake
12. Uproot Bonneter
13. Roving Racer
14. Scoreboard
15. First Shepherd Steam Gardener
16. Second Shepherd Steam Gardener
17. Peach
18. Glydon
19. Captain Toad
20. Deep Woods Steam Gardener
21. Hint Art

## Cloud Kingdom

1. Hint Toad
2. Uncle Amiibo
3. Paint Toad
4. Peach

## Lost Kingdom

1. Roving Racer
2. Scoreboard
3. Hint Toad
4. Uncle Amiibo
5. Luigi
6. Tropical Wiggler Bonneter
7. Talkatoo
8. Toad that points to the Captain
9. Captain Toad
10. Toad outside Crazy Cap
11. Purple Crazy Cap Toad
12. Yellow Crazy Cap Toad
13. Peach
14. Glydon

## Metro Kingdom

1. Luigi
2. Uncle Amiibo
3. Hint Toad
4. Bonneter looking for friend
5. Music Toad
6. Talkatoo
7. Taxi Tostarenan
8. Jump rope scoreboard
9. Bassist
10. Hat and Seek Bonneter (Squawks Park)
11. Roving Racer
12. Foot race scoreboard
13. New Donker talking about power lines
14. Side somersault sign
15. Hat lady
16. Guitarist
17. Drummer
18. Pauline (outside city hall)
19. Captain Toad
20. Guy needing to be cheered up
21. Hat and Seek Bonneter (in the crowd)
22. Construction guy
23. New Donker to start the festival
24. Pauline (festival)
25. Peach
26. Hint Art
27. Trumpeter
28. Purple Crazy Cap New Donker
29. Yellow Crazy Cap New Donker
30. RC Bouncer
31. RC Scoreboard

## Snow Kingdom

1. Hint Toad
2. Uncle Amiibo
3. Luigi
4. Roving Racer
5. Freerunning scoreboard
6. Koopa Trace Walking
7. Snow Cheep Cheep Bonneter
8. Hint Art
9. Shiverian Elder (Snowline Circuit)
10. Snowline scoreboard
11. Shiverian Elder (Iceburn Circuit)
12. Iceburn scoreboard